# JQuery Validation Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I doing a field validation using jquery to check if it is empty.  If it is I want to display a message and then refocus on the field so the user can enter some data. Code:

```
$('#fieldId').blur(function() {
    var fieldValue = $(this).val();
    if(fieldValue == null || fieldValue.length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('error');
        // show error message
        $('#errorDivId')
            .text('You must enter a value in this field')
            .show();
        $(this).focus();
    }
    else {
        if ($(this).is('.error')) {
            $(this.removeClass('error');
            $('#errorDivId').hide()
        }
    }
});
```

It sort of works but it moves the cursor to the next field and not the one I refocused on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('#fieldId').blur(function(evt) {
  var fieldValue = $(this).val();
  if(fieldValue == null || fieldValue.length == 0) {
    $(this).addClass('error');
    // show error message
    $('#errorDivId')
        .text('You must enter a value in this field')
        .show();
    this.focus();
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
    if ($(this).is('.error')) {
        $(this.removeClass('error');
        $('#errorDivId').hide()
    }
  }
});
```

However that may not completely solve the problem, as some browsers might be confused.  As an alternative, wrap your "focus" call up as a timeout and run it after the current event finishes:

```
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() { self.focus(); }, 1);
```

It's kind-of a hack but it should also work.

*edit* — @Gus is right about which "focus()" to call

Answer (score 2):

The `blur` event is triggered during a focus change (as the control you are validating loses focus). This could cause weird behaviour if you try to alter the focus while it is already changing. Instead of `blur`, try attaching the validation to the `change` event.

Also, there's no need to call the jQuery version of focus: `$(this).focus()`, you can just call `this.focus()`.

```
$('#fieldId').change(function() {
    var fieldValue = $(this).val(); 
    if(fieldValue == null || fieldValue.length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('error');
        // show error message
        $('#errorDivId').text('You must enter a value in this field').show(); 
        this.focus(); 
    } else {
        if ($(this).is('.error')) { 
            $(this).removeClass('error');
            $('#errorDivId').hide() 
        } 
    }
});
```